# Does the Higgs field have an energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

I have many questions about the notion of space.  I learned that at the quantum level, energy became quantized and that the infinite sum of energy states can no longer be substitued by integrals (because of the ultraviolet catastrophe).

I was wondering if space could also be quantized at a very small scale, if there were "space quanta". Trying to connect this to the ultraviolet catastrophe, I thought that this could be true if space contained an energy in itself.

I don't really know what the Higgs field is, but I believe that it is ubiquitous in space. So I was wondering if it has energy, and if this could be linked to "space quanta" (or if I am totally wrong).

Comment: To quantize space we really need a theory of quantum gravity (i.e. to incorporate spacetime). The UV catastrophe and calculations in QFT are done around a fixed Minkowski background. I don't see any link between this & the Higgs field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higgs field is the result of a charged scalar field (where scalar means that it has no spin, charged means that it has a charge for the interaction you want to give mass) which oscillates around a vacuum states. It has energy as every scalar field carries energy, in the sense that excitation of the scalar field as an energy.

The problem of ultraviolet divergence (or catastrophe) is resolved, as you said, if spacetime is quantized and not continuous. The lattice quantum field theory studies quantum field theory on a discrete spacetime. Doing this type of theory, you resolve the problem of divergences: the calculation of cross section needs Feynman diagram and if there is any loop you should integrate on momenta from 0 to infinity, but if spacetime is discrete you have simmetry for translation so you have just to integrate in the first Brillouin zone, i.e. $[-\frac{\pi}{a},\frac{\pi}{a}]$ where $a$ is the spacing of the spacetime lattice and this integral has no divergences.